# How can I remove the white background of my transparent icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm using transparent forum icons, but I've a problem with the white background of the image: [image]

How can I remove it using CSS or a software?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless the background is being added by CSS, you need an image with an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make your image like this where the white is transparent?

[image: Like this]

[image: done]

Photoshop took about 2 seconds. Select the white and delete it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm using a color picker, so I want that the white background is transparent.

Comment: Right click the image I made for you and save it. You should look into any number of image editing tools. Photoshop by Adobe is a flag ship software but there is many others available.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using a color picker, so the result is not good: http://prntscr.com/5up82x

Comment: Yes I see.  Ideally you would need to create vector based icons scale them to size and add them to your sprite.  This sprite has been pixelated even after removing the background gray specs exist. There is nothing you can do about this except recreate your sprite.

Comment: Or how can I make the white background like this color please? rgb(245, 246, 247)

Comment: Ive updated the image above, it looks fine with that background. Both images I made would work. Top one is transparent bottom one is static.

Comment: Can you please use the default image I posted in my first post and change only the white background to the color I posted? Because I use a color picker. I think it's the best solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Save the images in the .PNG format. JPEG images can not handle transparency. Photoshop has this capability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to re-size the image after being inserted, then try the following code in the css part -

background: transparent url("/static/img/image.png") center center no-repeat;

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is now fixed. I changed the white background to the same background of my element: http://prntscr.com/5upc73 and https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq2pw.png